# iOS 17 - URL encoding and not working with server API

Tags: ios, swift, url

I've an app that should call this API:

```
http://109.168.113.11/Acucgi/G7TestWeb.sh?funzione=charge_pms&utente=WXWX&password=TESTWWW1&azienda=RISTORANTE&modo=Json&fl_ad=A&camera=5&data_del=20231004&codadd[0]=V10&qtaadd[0]=1&impadd[0]=7,80&desadd[0]=Cappuccinos
```

In my app I've developed a class who can call this API, but from iOS 17 I've several problem because Apple has updated to RFC 3986 the url encoding.
Here's my code:

```
let urlString = "http://109.168.113.11/Acucgi/G7TestWeb.sh?funzione=charge_pms&utente=WXWX&password=TESTWWW1&azienda=RISTORANTE&modo=Json&fl_ad=A&camera=5&data_del=20231004&codadd[0]=V10&qtaadd[0]=1&impadd[0]=7,80&desadd[0]=Cappuccinos"
guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
    print("!! url !!")
    return
}
var request = URLRequest(url: sysDatUrl)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
      [MANAGE RESPONSE]
}
```

By using this code the server answer me an error because my app use the following url:

```
http://109.168.113.11/Acucgi/G7TestWeb.sh?funzione=charge_pms&utente=WXWX&password=TESTWWW1&azienda=RISTORANTE&modo=Json&fl_ad=A&camera=5&data_del=20231004&codadd%5B0%5D=V10&qtaadd%5B0%5D=1&impadd%5B0%5D=7,80&desadd%5B0%5D=Cappuccinos
```

As you can see in my url iOS changed the character `[` with `%5B` and `]` with `%5D`. To work with my server I must use the `[` and `]`, if I use the `%5B` and `%5D` my integration will not work anymore. There's a way to keep the character `[` and `]`?
Thank you

Comment: The issue is server side - characters like `[` and `]` are not allowed URL characters, so the ate percent-encoded. Your server should expect to receive those characters percent encoded. If anything, it's weird that prior to iOS 17 the URL initializer returned valid URL instance when passed a string without those characters percent encoded

Comment: If this is really **your** server don't misuse the URL query to pass hard-coded index subscription syntax. A better syntax could be to pass the index separately `…data_del=20231004&codadd=V10&qtaadd=1&impadd=7,80&desadd=Cappuccinos&addIndex=0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string that your server requires is not a valid URL, which means that your server implements a protocol that is similar to HTTP, but is not actually HTTP. Apple's frameworks only support certain protocols, and do not support this non-standard protocol that your server implements. There is no way to express an invalid URL as an `URL`.

The best solution is to correct your server so that it decodes HTTP  messages properly. That includes handling percent-encoded URIs.

If cannot or do not wish to modify your server, then you'll need to implement this custom protocol by hand. Since this is very close to HTTP, that's pretty easy.

This is the kind of code you'd write. I haven't tested it much, but it should hopefully get you one the right path:

```
class Client {
    var connection: NWConnection?

    // You need to split the host, port, and query. You must encode this "path" exactly
    // as you need it to be sent. It won't be further encoded.
    let host = NWEndpoint.Host("109.168.113.11")
    let port = NWEndpoint.Port(80)
    let path = "/Acucgi/G7TestWeb.sh?funzione=charge_pms&utente=WXWX&password=TESTWWW1&azienda=RISTORANTE&modo=Json&fl_ad=A&camera=5&data_del=20231004&codadd[0]=V10&qtaadd[0]=1&impadd[0]=7,80&desadd[0]=Cappuccinos"

    // This is the important method, which constructs an HTTP request by hand.
    // This is where you need to make sure that you send whatever your server requires.
    func sendRequest() {
        let data = Data("""
        GET \(path) HTTP/1.1\r
        Host: \(host)\r
        \r
        \r
        """.utf8)
        connection?.send(content: data, isComplete: true, completion: .idempotent)
    }

    // This is where you handle what is returned
    func handle(data: Data) {
        print(String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self))
    }

    // The rest is somewhat boilerplate code for handling NWConnection.
    // It's roughly based on Eskimo's work.
    // https://forums.swift.org/t/socket-api/19971/6

    func start() {
        // `.tcp` here is what you want for HTTP.
        // For HTTPS, you'd change the port to 443 and use `.tls` here.
        let connection = NWConnection(host: host, port: port, using: .tcp)
        connection.stateUpdateHandler = self.stateDidChange(to:)
        self.setupReceive(on: connection)
        self.connection = connection
        connection.start(queue: .main)
    }

    func stateDidChange(to state: NWConnection.State) {
        switch state {
        case .setup:
            break
        case .waiting(let error):
            self.connectionDidFail(error: error)
        case .preparing:
            break
        case .ready:
            sendRequest()
        case .failed(let error):
            self.connectionDidFail(error: error)
        case .cancelled:
            break
        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }

    func setupReceive(on connection: NWConnection) {
        connection.receive(minimumIncompleteLength: 1, maximumLength: 65536) { (data, contentContext, isComplete, error) in
            if let data = data, !data.isEmpty {
                self.handle(data: data)
            }
            if isComplete {
                // … handle end of stream …
                self.stop()
            } else if let error = error {
                self.connectionDidFail(error: error)
            } else {
                self.setupReceive(on: connection)
            }

        }
    }
    func connectionDidFail(error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }

    func stop() {
        // Handle shutting down
    }
}


let client = Client()
client.start()
```